# How to make "menus" without functions or not call them inside eachother?

Tags: python, function, menu, console-application

Im learning python and I already know the basics. So i'm trying to make a simple program: "A note pad".

Im only using the console and I want to have the following menus
**main menu, read note menu, write menu, etc.** To do that i'm using a function for each menu, printing the menu, using `input()` to choose the next menu and then I call the function of the next menu.

But if I have a `try` / `except` block in a "a menu", and there's an error in another function called inside that block it will go back and execute the `except` block.

How can might I be able to avoid this, or is there any better way to make the menus?

**Here's what I have:**

```
noteList = [["Here goes the title", "Here goes the text", "Here goes the date"], ["Example", "Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text", "08/08/2020"]] # note list

#-------------Main Menu-------------
def mainMenu():
    print(*"NOTES")                   # title

    print("Write:")
    print('-The number of the note to read;')
    print('-[N] to create a [N]ew note;')
    print('-[D] to [D]elete a note;')
    print('-[E] to [E]xit;')

# saved notes
    if len(noteList) == 0:            # no saved notes
        print("\nYou have no notes.")
    else:                             # display saved notes
        print("\nSaved notes:")
        for number in range(len(noteList)):
            print(str(number + 1) + "-" + noteList[number][0])
            
# ask what action to do
    action = input()
    actionChooser(action)

#-------------Action Chooser-------------   
def actionChooser(action):
    try:
        action = int(action) - 1                # action is int
        readNote(action)

    except:
        if action == "N" or action == "n":      # action is N
            newNote()
            
        elif action == "D" or action == "d":    # action is E
            deleteNote()
            
        elif action == "E" or action == "e":    # action is S
            exit()
            
        else:                                   # invalid action
            print("Invalid action.\n")
            mainMenu()
#---------------------------------------
def readNote(noteNumber):
    print(*"\n" + noteList[noteNumber][0].upper())
    print(noteList[noteNumber][1])

mainMenu()
```

*Thanks and my apologies if I have accedently broken one of your rules it's my first post here.*

Comment: Don't worry that's a pretty well written question for your first time!

Answer (score 1):

I will describe how I see it in pseudocode:

```
1. start program
2. defining processing functions
3. print instructions
4. endless loop
  5. wait for input
  6. action with try/except
7. exit program
```

And example program:

```
import sys

def action_howto():
    print("""Instructions:
        'test' for action_test
        'exit' for exit
    """)

def action_test():
    print("action_test executed\n")

def action_exit():
    sys.exit("bye-bye")

def do_action(action):
    try:
        {
            "test": action_test,
            "exit": action_exit
        }.get(action.lower(), action_howto)()
    except Exception as e:
        action_howto()

def main():
    action_howto()
    while True:
        action = input()
        do_action(action)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```